# Web Design - What is that style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I was wondering if there was a name for this 'style' of web design
(sorry, these are the only examples I could come up with atm):

http://www.apple.com/watch/?cid=wwa-us-kwg-watch-com

http://www.codecademy.com/

I see it used frequently and want to try to do something similar as an excercise.

The style is very vertical and has a feel of 'defined' sections as you scroll vertically... I don't know how else to explain it, hopefully the pages are proper examples.

Comment: Do you mean like are they a single page app?

Comment: Usually they are single page with no links to other pages but links to sections within the page...is that what they are called though, a single page app?

Comment: ok well i just google 'single page app' and it looks like that's what i'm looking for... thank you!!

Comment: I believe they are just a single page layout. When you click a navigation link it scrolls to the section that the link refers to.

Comment: This belongs on graphic design imo

Comment: It's called  a website with a scrollbar and anchors

Comment: it is called one page (or one pager HTML)
you can check this website for free template

http://designscrazed.org/free-responsive-html5-css3-templates/

Comment: Note that the term "Single-Page App" also means something else that's considerably different.

Comment: Can you please explain.. because now I'm not so sure that SPA is the answer ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The websites are called "single page presentation" or "one page presentation"

Answer (score 0):

What's notable about about the design of those sites is their [responsive layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).  Their block-style presentation has no particular name.  You can employ a similar technique using the [Twitter Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) as they have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you about 2 years ago, this is what brought out more and better results in google:

[One Page Scrolling Website](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=one%20page%20scrolling%20website&oq=one%20page%20scr&aqs=chrome.3.0j69i65j69i57j0l3.2967j0j7)